Gitlab agent on k8s: Failed to register agent pod. Please make sure the agent version matches the server version
Summary
I'm trying to install gitlab agent on a K3S cluster using Helm exactly the command provided from the gitlab kubernetes cluster dashboard:
Versions

Chart: gitlab-agent-2.0.0

Platform:

Self-hosted: Rancher K3S


Kubernetes: (kubectl version)

Client Version: v1.29.1
Kustomize Version: v5.0.4-0.20230601165947-6ce0bf390ce3
Server Version: v1.28.4+k3s2


Helm: (helm version)

version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.14.1", GitCommit:"e8858f8696b144ee7c533bd9d49a353ee6c4b98d", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.21.7"}



Relevant logs
{"level":"info","time":"2024-05-22T07:39:03.300Z","msg":"Observability endpoint is up","mod_name":"observability","net_network":"tcp","net_address":"[::]:8080"}
{"level":"error","time":"2024-05-22T07:39:03.393Z","msg":"Failed to register agent pod. Please make sure the agent version matches the server version","mod_name":"agent_registrar","error":"rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = unavailable"}
{"level":"error","time":"2024-05-22T07:39:17.595Z","msg":"Failed to register agent pod. Please make sure the agent version matches the server version","mod_name":"agent_registrar","error":"rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = unavailable"}


helm upgrade --install k8s-connection-poc gitlab/gitlab-agent 
--namespace gitlab-agent-k8s-connection-poc 
--create-namespace 
--set config.token=token 
--set config.kasAddress=wss://secf-gitlab-bis.secf.asso.fr/-/kubernetes-agent/ 
--set-file config.kasCaCert=gitlab.crt
But the agent is not connecting

when I check the logs of the pods I get this:
"msg":"Failed to register agent pod. Please make sure the agent version matches the server version","mod_name":"agent_registrar","error":"rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = unavailable"}

I encountered a similar issue while installing the GitLab agent on a K3S cluster. Here’s what I did to resolve it:

Check your GitLab server logs: When I attempted to install the agent, I encountered an error ending with ...tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate relies on legacy Common Name field, use SANs instead.
The logs from the GitLab server helped me identify this issue.

GitLab and Nginx configuration: In my case, my GitLab is self-hosted via a docker-compose setup. I also use Nginx as a reverse proxy (Nginx Proxy Manager). If you have a similar setup, could you share your docker-compose configuration?
To fix my issue, I had to modify the GitLab docker-compose file to run GitLab over HTTP and let Nginx handle the HTTPS redirection. Here’s how I configured my docker-compose for GitLal.
look this exemple :
My config with the issue :
With the patch

I encountered this error too, you have to add your root self-signed certificate that gitlab certificate is signed with (or ssl, depending on how you did it) to the trusted-certs directory (/etc/gitlab/trusted-certs/)
https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/ssl/ssl_troubleshooting.html#custom-certificates-missing-or-skipped
As I understand gitlab kas service redirects requests not through localhost, but through external https interface of gitlab itself, because of which it may not know about it (especially if gitlab server is deployed in the docker).
To summarize:

You have a certificate /opt/rootca.crt (rename it to rootca.pem).
Add the certificate to gitlab (/etc/gitlab/trusted-certs)

cp /opt/rootca.pem /etc/gitlab/trusted-certs/
# restart gitlab or reconfigure
gitlab-ctl reconfigure
#or
docker restart gitlab


Install helm agent

helm repo add gitlab https://charts.gitlab.io
helm repo update
helm upgrade --install my-agent gitlab/gitlab-agent \
    --namespace gitlab-agent \
    --create-namespace \
    --set image.tag=v17.0.0 \
    --set config.token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \
    --set config.kasAddress=wss://gitlab.my.domain/-/kubernetes-agent/ \
    --set-file config.kasCaCert=/opt/rootca.pem 


Enjoy.


I had the exact same problem as described and was finally able to resolve it. I'm sharing the steps here in the hope it might be helpful.
Besides the pods and nginx logs in gitlab, there is the gitlab-kas log file (/var/log/gitlab/gitlab-kas/current)

2024-06-28_15:28:50.77417
{"level":"error","time":"2024-06-28T17:28:50.774+0200","msg":"AgentInfo()","grpc_service":"gitlab.agent.reverse_tunnel.rpc.ReverseTunnel","grpc_method":"Connect","error":"Get
"http://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/internal/kubernetes/agent_info":
dial tcp: lookup gitlab.example.com on 192.168.64.1:53: no such host"}

My mistake was setting a wrong "external_url" (gitlab.example.com) value in the configuration file. Fix it and reconfigure gitlab
# First correct the value in the configuration file
vi /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb
# Then reconfigure gitlab
gitlab-ctl reconfigure

